# Doctrine: Class is not a valid entity or mapped super class, error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

So I am getting the famous:

```
[RuntimeException]
Namespace "MyAppSomeToolBundle" does not contain any mapped entities.

doctrine:generate:entities [--path="..."] [--no-backup] name
```

I tried searching for any answers on stackoverflow but nothing seems to work. It seems like my code is properly formated. I also have :

```
orm:
    auto_mapping: true
```

**I get the error when executing:**

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MyApp\SomeToolBundle\Entity\Lang
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    namespace MyApp\SomeToolBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     *  @ORM\Entity
     *  @ORM\Table(name="phonetics")
     */
    class Lang
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="text")
         */
        protected $language;
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="text")
         */
        protected $text;
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="text")
         */
        protected $option1;
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="text")
         */
        protected $option2;
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="text")
         */
        protected $rated;
    }
?>
```

So I am not sure how to properly debug this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities` ? The error tells you that you've already created entities manually.

You probably wish to generate database tables by executing the following at your application folder.

`php -f ./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module.php orm:schema-tool:update --force`

You can view sql before executing:

`php -f ./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module.php orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql`

Comment: Actually. I am doing it because in the Symfony's instruction manual, it says the following on page 84: "php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Acme/StoreBundle/Entity/Product
This command makes sure that all of the getters and setters are generated for the Product class. This is
a safe command - you can run it over and over again: it only generates getters and setters that don't exist
(i.e. it doesn't replace your existing methods)."